# Spark create or replace temp view not updating existing table multiple times

Tags: csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

**Step-1**
I need to compare two csv files reaptedly while one being static (`DB.csv`)  and other is downloaded from web `Downloaded.csv` (which is dynamic,may be updated records )

**Step-2**
After comparing the difference from both two csv,will be writen to mongodb

**Step-3**
Now `Downloaded.csv` file need to replace `DB.csv`, then same logic from step-1 will continue.

> **Sample explanation**

*Step-1*

```
DB.csv   [temp table `db` ]

sno APPLE   BANANA
1   13  11
2   2   22
3   2   22

Downloaded.csv [temp table `downloaded` ]
sno APPLE   BANANA
1   n   11
2   2   22
3   2   22
```

*Step-2*

```
Difference dataset
sno APPLE   BANANA
1     n       11
```

*Step-3*

```
DB.csv [temp table `db` - updated ]
sno APPLE   BANANA
 1  n   11
 2  2   22
 3  2   22
```

**Repeating** *Step-1*

```
DB.csv [temp table `db` - updated ]
sno APPLE   BANANA
 1  n   11
 2  2   22
 3  2   22

Downloaded.csv [temp table `downloaded` - new downloaded record ]
sno APPLE   BANANA
1   n   11
2   2   n
3   2   22
```

**Repeating** *Step-2*

```
Difference dataset
sno APPLE   BANANA
2     2       n
```

**Repeating** *Step-3*

```
DB.csv [temp table `db` ]
sno APPLE   BANANA
 1  n   11
 2  2   n
 3  2   22
```

> **Here is my logic**

```
 Dataset<Row> downloaded =spark.read().option("header","true").csv("/home/exa4/Desktop/downloaded.csv");
     Dataset<Row> db =spark.read().option("header","true").csv("/home/exa4/Desktop/db.csv");
     downloaded.createOrReplaceTempView("downloaded");
     db.createOrReplaceTempView("db");

     Dataset<Row> diffs= spark.sql("select * from downloaded EXCEPT select * from db");

    //write updates to collection
    MongoSpark.save(diffs.write().option("collection", "UpdatedRecords").mode("overwrite"));

    //replacing old DB with new dataset downloaded 
    downloaded.createOrReplaceTempView("db");

     ////For every 10 seconds I may intenstionaly change the downloaded.csv for testing , as it is dynamic dataset 
     while(true){
         long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Thread.sleep(10000);

             //this will be newly downloaded file from net 
             Dataset<Row> downloaded =spark.read().option("header","true").csv("/home/exa4/Desktop/downloaded.csv");
             downloaded.createOrReplaceTempView("downloaded");

            //now comparing downloaded with previously updated dataset 
            Dataset<Row> diffs_= spark.sql("select * from downloaded EXCEPT select * from db");
            diffs_.show();
             ////HERE I AM GETTING NULL RECORDS 

            downloaded.createOrReplaceTempView("db");

     }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
spark.catalog.refreshTable(s"$dbName.$destinationTableName")
```

replace with dbname and table name